# Content inside Sitecore placeholders does not render to the page after Sitecore upgrade

Tags: upgrade, placeholders

I have upgraded a website from Sitecore 7.2 rev 140526 to 8.2 rev 161129 using Express Migration tool. After doing all config changes, recompiling existing dlls with new sitecore dlls and other post upgrade steps, I was able to login and do functionalities in Sitecore back-end.

But when I view the public website, content inside placeholders does not renders to the webpage. But when I add Sublayout tag instead of Placeholder to the page and bind the presenatation component statistically it works fine. I cannot find any errors in the logs either.

Any suggestion to fix this?

Comment: Shot in the dark, is the case between you key in layouts different that the key in the placeholder setting. I remember having this issue, but it may have been 7.5.

Answer (score 1):

Is your content visible in this window:

[image: Layout details final layout]

If yes, identify the correct placeholder path by placing a new control on the page where you're sure it renders and copy that into the placeholder field of your existing items:

[image: Placeholder field location]

Alternatively, check the current placeholder field value and adjust your page/partial designs to use that, maybe it got changed during the upgrade.

Comment: Yes. I checked the presentation details and placeholder field values. All those things are matched to the placeholder keys in the layout.